# How can I make an img stack in front of an h1?

Tags: html, css, z-index

In [this example of a legend](https://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/gfxoh38v/), I have a little "info" image that will be used for a tooltip when you hover over it. However, other elements seem to be stacking on top of the image, even when I set the `z-index` of the image to a very high number. How can I make it so that the image is stacked on top so that my tooltip works properly?

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
#foreignPartTooltip {
  z-index: 9999999;
}
.icon16 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: help;
}
.s101-fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.s101-fieldset h1 {
  font: 12px Verdana;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.s101-fieldset h1 span {
  display: inline;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px 4px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -17px;
}
.s101-fieldset > .s101-fieldset-content {
  padding: 8px;
}
.s101-fieldset > .s101-fieldset-content .legend-item {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  cursor: default;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
.s101-fieldset > .s101-fieldset-content .legend-national-part {
  margin: 3px 2px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: gold;
}
.s101-fieldset > .s101-fieldset-content .legend-local-part {
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}
.s101-fieldset > .s101-fieldset-content .legend-foreign-part {
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.s101-fieldset > .s101-fieldset-content .legend-item-horizontal {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.s101-fieldset > .s101-fieldset-content .legend-item-horizontal:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="s101-fieldset">
  <h1><span>LEGEND</span></h1>
  <div class="s101-fieldset-content">
    <div class="legend-item legend-national-part legend-item-horizontal">National part</div>
    <div class="legend-item legend-local-part legend-item-horizontal">Local part</div>
    <div class="legend-item legend-foreign-part legend-item-horizontal">
      Foreign part
      <img title="Hey there!" id="foreignPartTooltip" src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/royal-blue/info-xxl.png" class="icon16" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `h1` is on the top. You need to set the `z-index` of the `.s101-fieldset-content` div, instead of the img. Or you can set `position: relative;` to the `.s101-fieldset-content` div, and it will be o top of the `h1`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gfxoh38v/2/) you have the working code

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. Just for my knowledge, however... *why* does this solution work? Why is setting the z-index of the image itself not sufficient?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements can help you to understand how position fixed, absolute and relative interact with z-index.

Answer (score 2):

The position of your `<h1>` tag covers the block below it. I suggest you use the [legend html tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend), because it was created for that purpose:

```css
.icon16 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: help;
}

.s101-fieldset legend {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}

.s101-fieldset .s101-fieldset-content {
    padding: 8px;
}

.s101-fieldset .s101-fieldset-content .legend-item {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    font: 13px Verdana;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

.s101-fieldset .s101-fieldset-content .legend-national-part {
    margin: 3px 2px 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: gold;
}

.s101-fieldset .s101-fieldset-content .legend-local-part {
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: white;
}

.s101-fieldset .s101-fieldset-content .legend-foreign-part {
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.s101-fieldset .s101-fieldset-content .legend-item-horizontal {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.s101-fieldset .s101-fieldset-content .legend-item-horizontal:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="s101-fieldset">
    <fieldset>
        <legend align="center">
            LEGEND
        </legend>
        <div class="s101-fieldset-content">
            <div class="legend-item legend-national-part legend-item-horizontal">National part</div>
            <div class="legend-item legend-local-part legend-item-horizontal">Local part</div>
            <div class="legend-item legend-foreign-part legend-item-horizontal">
                Foreign part
                <img id="foreignPartTooltip" src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/royal-blue/info-xxl.png" class="icon16" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This does solve my issue, however I'm intentionally not using the `fieldset` and `legend` elements because of some other display limitations. But still +1 because it does solve the issue.